# Sub-setting elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, subset, apply

Assume that this is my list

```
a <- list(c(1,2,4))
a[[2]] <- c(2,10,3,2,7)
a[[3]] <- c(2, 2, 14, 5)
```

How do I subset this list to exclude all the 2's.  How do I obtain the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]]
[1] 10  3  7

[[3]]
[1] 14  5
```

My current solution:

```
for(j in seq(1, length(a))){
  a[[j]] <- a[[j]][a[[j]] != 2]
}
```

However, this approach feels a bit unnatural.  How would I do the same thing with a function from the apply family?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(a, function(x) x[x != 2])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 4
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 10  3  7
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 14  5
```

Using `lapply` you can apply the subset to each vector in the list. The subset used is, `x[x != 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `setdiff` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(a, setdiff, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 10  3  7

#[[3]]
#[1] 14  5
```